# finding anti-derivative to $\sin^5$(x) through Euler

Tags: integration

I get that $\int\sin^5(x)dx$ will be $$\int\frac{1}{(2i)^5}(e^{5ix}-5e^{3ix}-10e^{ix}-10e^{-ix}+5e^{-3ix}-e^{-5ix}) dx$$

like this: $$\int\frac{1}{(2i)^5}(e^{5ix}-e^{-5ix})+(5e^{-3ix}-5e^{3ix})+(10e^{ix}-10e^{-ix}) dx$$

which I figured out is $$\frac{1}{(2i)^5}\int\sin(5x)+10\sin(x)+(5e^{-3ix}-5e^{3ix})dx $$

How do I calculate $$(5e^{-3ix}-5e^{3ix}) \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{1}{(2i)^5}$$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, but there are a few things to point out. You should have $$\int\frac{1}{(2i)^5}(e^{5ix}-e^{-5ix})+(5e^{-3ix}-5e^{3ix})+(10e^{ix}-10e^{-ix}) dx \\ = \frac{1}{(2i)^4}\int \frac{(e^{5ix}-e^{-5ix})+(5e^{-3ix}-5e^{3ix})+(10e^{ix}-10e^{-ix})}{2i}dx \\ = \frac{1}{(2i)^4}\int \frac{(e^{5ix}-e^{-5ix})-(5e^{3ix}-5e^{-3ix})+(10e^{ix}-10e^{-ix})}{2i}dx $$ where it should be more clear now that $ -\frac{(5e^{3ix}-5e^{-3ix})}{2i} = -5\sin(3x)$. Next, $\frac{1}{(2i)^4}$ is just a constant so there is no need to integrate it. It can remain outside the integral, and upon evaluation you should find $\frac{1}{(2i)^4} = \frac{1}{16}$.

Comment: Now get it, thanks! Though you forgot to integrate everything :)

Comment: Oops! I'll just remove that haha. Glad to hear you got it